# in node.js, cannot get rid of a bad symlink

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I have an `uglify` function that creates a file `lib-0.1.4-min.js` and then symlinks that to `lib-production-min.js`.  `0.1.4` is the current version.

due to synchronization of this directory, sometimes the `lib-production-min.js` is a broken link.

when I run the compile function, `fs.existsSync( "lib-production-min.js" )` returns false.  when I try to create the symlink later, `node` errs out with `file already exists`.

```
var version = 'lib-0.1.4-min.j';
var prod = 'lib-production-min.js';

// if production exists, get rid of it
if( fs.existsSync(prod) ) fs.unlinkSync( prod );  // not exists - not deleted

// link version to production
fs.symlinkSync( version, prod );                  // ERROR: file already exists
```

1. how do I check if this deadlink is in the directory?
2. will normal `fs.unlinkSync( "lib-production-min.js" )` delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fs.lstat()` or `fs.lstatSync()` might help you. They are supposed to bring the information about the link itself, not following it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fs.readlinkSync(symlinkPath)` to get the file pointed by the symlink, and then use `fs.existsSync` with that path.

The problem is that the link file exists, is the destination of the link the one that is missing.